# Facebook post not visible even with public privacy

Tags: android, facebook, share

I'm using Facebook SDK 3 for android to share status in my wall .. I authorize the publication to be visible to all my friend , The post is well published but no one can see it expect me , even with privacy :public

```
private void postStatusUpdate() {
        if (user != null && hasPublishPermission()) {
            final String message = getString(R.string.status_update, user.getFirstName(), (new Date().toString()));
            Request request = Request
                    .newStatusUpdateRequest(Session.getActiveSession(), message, new Request.Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                            showPublishResult(message, response.getGraphObject(), response.getError());
                        }
                    });
            request.executeAsync();
        } else {
            pendingAction = PendingAction.POST_STATUS_UPDATE;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the standbox mode ( desactivate it )